# What is a abbreviation of rvmrc?

Tags: rvm

what is a abbreviation of .rvmrc ?

Where we generally mention

`rvm use 1.9.3@test --create`

In new version of rvm is that file been depricated?

Comment: I think there is no particular abbreviation followed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.rvmrc files are more like a setup files, or precursor for commands in case needed.

rvm stands for Ruby Version Manager and rc stands for Runtime Configuration. To put in simple abbreciation it is **R**uby **V**ersion **M**anager **R**untime **C**onfiguration.

Comment: Thank you . Can you reply for the other question? so that i can accept your answer?

Comment: They are not deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

`.rvmrc` files are not deprecated, there are other formats that sometimes fit better your project and this is why you get a message about them, it does not mean `.rvmrc` goes away as this file has it's own features that can not be easily replaced when using for example `.ruby-version`.